# is there a way to add two numbers together creating one two digit number?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm currently losing sleep over this problem I have and I would be grateful if someone could help me.

The problem itself is simple. I have two variables, let's call them `x` and `y` and I want these two variables to make one number: `z`. so for example let `x = 3` and `y = 7` I need `z` to be `37`

I know the answer is simple as well but I just can't find the search words for it. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. Perhaps the most simple is to use strings:

```
>>> int(f'{x}{y}')
37
```

Or you can just use math. This is also very simple, especially if you know that each of your integers is a single digit:

```
>>> x*10+y
37
```

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

```
str(x) + str(y)                                                                                                                                                                     
#  '37'
```

or

```
int(str(x) + str(y))                                                                                                                                                                
# 37
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simply convert them to str:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
result = ''
for n in numbers:
  result += str(n)
print(result)
# 1234
```